# Postman "Could not complete OAuth 2.0 login" when using Imgur API

Tags: postman, imgur

Here is what Imgur says I should do
[image]

Here is what I am doing
[image]

And after I hit `Request Token` I am redirected to give access[image]

And After I give access [image]

Any suggestions on how I could fix this?

Comment: I believe that Imgur is broken at the moment. I myself have an app which used to login just fine and then suddenly stopped logging in somewhere during the beginning of July. I wrote to Imgur support, but no reply.

For the record: I'm getting an http error 400 with a json reply which states that the callback URL is missing or not matching the registered one; and once I retry, I get error 500 ("Imgur is temporarily over capacity. Please try again later").

Comment: @mardy try encoding `redirect_uri` request parameter: instead of `redirect_uri=http://localhost` put `redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost`

Comment: Thanks @Valya, that fixed my issue! I wish the error message had been more informative. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into the same issue, got fixed by changing the callback url from `https://www.getpostman.com/yada/yada/yada` to `https://imgur.com`. I also changed the postman version from the chrome app to the desktop version, I'm not sure if this did the trick or not.

Answer (score 0):

on your account you need to channge the callback url

[imgur change redirect url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqYwu.png)